# Reloading keybindings.json without restarting vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to reload `keybindings.json` in vscode without having to fully restart the editor?

Answer (score 1):

You can reload your current window without restarting VSCode.

This will refresh your keybindings

1. **Open:** `Command Palette`

   - **Windows/Linux:** `Ctrl + Shift + P`
   - **Mac:** `⌘ + Shift + P`
2. **Type:** `reload`
3. **Select:** `Developer: Reload Window`

Answer (score 0):

The keybindings.json file is watched by VS Code so editing it while VS Code is running will update the rules at runtime.

Comment: Yes, but only if you're editing the `keybindings.json` file in the current VSCode window. Other windows will not automatically reload it.